# Expanding included files in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, notepad++

I am trying to run a PHP script and getting error on lines 162, 197 etc. whereas the page has only 60 lines. 
I have included 5 other pages in the master page. Have used require_once to include them.
Is there a way I can expand them and see where the problem is?

I use Notepad++ for editing my code.

Regards,
Himanshu Joshi

Comment: I too use notepad++.  Let us know what the errors are and we can help you fix them.  It should tell you what error happened on X line.

Comment: What do you mean by expanding them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix. You need to pay more attention to the PHP error messages.

It says lines 162 and 197 of ***what files?***

If you only see numbers 162 & 197, then *somefile* is (at line 162) calling/loading some other code in line 197 of *theotherfile*.

Comment: I am actually trying to run oAuth on Yahoo. The error is shown on the file that contains require_once. The lines where it is showing error have <div> & <form> tags respectively, so the error must be in the expanded code. Is there any way I can see my complete code? The problem with me is that the code has six included files with pretty similar code..

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi, you need to right-click on the page and select "View Source" so that you can see the full output source including the error. I also recommend you setup PHP on your own machine so you don't have to write your app on the server.

Comment: I can see only HTML source by clicking view source. I want to see the exact line in the PHP code where the error is. Moreover I run PHP on my own machine only.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi, you're not making sense. If you see an error, then that error has a filename and line number for you to go to. Open that PHP file stated in the error and go to that line number. If the page is rendering an error in the browser (among HTML elements) then clicking "view source" will show you the full error message that you can use to get the filename and line number so you can know where to look.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is probably not the type of language that I expected on such forum. I am a novice and not a professional like you guys.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi, I have not said anything offensive. However, it seems clear that you are afraid to be upfront with your problem which is hindering us from helping you solve it. The solution is simple, share the *full error message* with us.